# How do I pass all elements of "array of hashes" into function as an array

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash, perl-data-structures

How do I pass a element of "array of hashes" into function as an array?

say for instance I wanted to pass all `$link->{text}` as an array into the `sort()` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $field = <<EOS;
<a href="baboon.html">Baboon</a>
<a href="antelope.html">Antelope</a>
<a href="dog.html">dog</a>
<a href="cat.html">cat</a>
EOS

#/ this comment is to unconfuse the SO syntax highlighter. 
my @array_of_links;
while ($field =~ m{<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a>}g) {
    push @array_of_links, { url => $1, text => $2 };
}
for my $link (@array_of_links) {
    print qq("$link->{text}" goes to -> "$link->{url}"\n);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort your links by text,

```
my @sorted_links = sort { $a->{text} cmp $b->{text} } @array_of_links;
```

If you actually just want to get and sort the text,

```
my @text = sort map $_->{text}, @array_of_links;
```

Comment: ysth: You might want to add a fallback clause in case the text fields are the same.  I'd do something like `sort { lc($a->{text}) cmp lc($b->{text}) || $a->{url} cmp $b->{url} }` but nicely aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Better to err on the side of caution and use an HTML parser to parse HTML:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $field = <<EOS;
<a href="baboon.html">Baboon</a>
<a href="antelope.html">Antelope</a>
<a href="dog.html">dog</a>
<a href="cat.html">cat</a>
EOS

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(string => $field);

my @urls;

while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag ) {
    next unless $tag->is_start_tag('a');
    next unless defined(my $url = $tag->get_attr('href'));
    my $text = $parser->get_text('/a');
    push @urls, { url => $url, text => $text };
}

@urls = sort {
    $a->{text} cmp $b->{text} ||
    $a->{url}  cmp $b->{url}
} @urls;

use YAML;
print Dump \@urls;
```